# Program to generate midi sounds and sequences

Tags: sound, mp3

I have a few songs I have written for a band using TuxGuitar, with the classic set of instruments: 2 guitars, 1 bass and drums. I can export this songs to MIDI, but since a while I've been searching for a program to "draw" my own waves and sounds in order to make these MIDI songs a little bit more attractive, somewhat like a gameboy 8bits songs. The question is **do you know about any helpful programs to do this?**

**Note:** I used once a program like this, but couldn't find it again since a friend showed it to me ages ago, it had a name like sandbox or alike. It allowed me to create custom sounds, defining the attack, sustain and other handy stuff as well as drawing the sound wave itself and sequence sounds.

Comment: I think this would be better on AVP. I'll send it over.

Comment: Could you add for which platform you want the program? This will help answerers.

Comment: Windows or Linux, I was  looking for a desktop tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trackers are a staple of the chiptune world. You should take a look at [Renoise](http://www.renoise.com).

You might be thinking of [Sunvox](http://www.warmplace.ru/soft/sunvox/), when you remember "sandbox".

Answer (score 3):

Here is such a synthesizer that allow you to "free hand" draw waves (all synthesizers allow adjusting attack, sustain, decay and so forth so for this purpose you can use about any synthesizer).

Throw this onto a MIDI and VST capable sequencer/DAW such as Cubase, Protools, Reason, FL etc.:

http://www.synthtopia.com/content/2010/12/18/free-wavetable-synthesizer-for-windows-freehand/

(you do have [this one for Gameboy](http://littlesounddj.com/) - not sure if that will help you out)